# Creating HTML layout/templates in a js/jquery bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

I currently have the following:

```
var inputDiv = $('<div/>').addClass('testing inputd').css({
    width: "90px",
    height: "245px",
    border: "1px solid #000",
    "background-color": "#fff",
    padding: "3px",
    position: "fixed",
    top: "30px",
    left: "10px",
    "z-index": "10000"
}); 
var tableDiv = $('<table/>').addClass('testing tabled').css({
    'border-collapse': 'collapse',
    'border-spacing': '2px',
    "z-index": "10000"
}); 
var tablecDiv = $('<div/>').addClass('testing tabledc').css({
    height: '195px',
    'overflow-y': 'auto',
    "z-index": "10000"
});
```

There are a lot of other entries like these and I append them all to one main div, and then append that to the body. This is SO ugly and incredibly hard to manage.

This is for a bookmarklet that is run on multiple users computers (FF/Chrome only) and cannot make external calls to .css or .html files and so on. Is there any other way to go about this?

Comment: why you want to put `addClass` to the end tags?

Comment: because the first thing the script does when it runs is look for the `testing` class and remove everything/unbind events and when the script runs it just remakes them. so if people click the bookmark multiple times it doesnt create multiple instances

Comment: call by `id` or `class` like this: `$("#id")` or `$(".class")`